# Implementing modular asp.net mvc project layout

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, modularity, convention

Here by modularity I do mean the feature based layout like this one:

[image: project's layout]

(I've read about areas. And I'm not asking about areas)

For example, using **NancyFx** this thing is achieved easilly. As for **ASP.NET MVC** I've tried to extend the standard `RazorViewEngine` by replacing its view search paths. As the result views were found but the static content they referenced couldn't be loaded (**404 error** with message saying that there's no corresponding controller to match a request to `/assets/css/dashboard.css`)

I have seen many posts where people implemented custom view engines, redefined the `CreateView`, `FindView`, `GetGeneralNameFrom` methods and so on. But I don't get the whole thing on the **ASP.NET MVC conventions**.

What conventions should be changed in order to let controllers reside with its feature-related code (services, views, models) in the same feature-folder?

I'm asking about the internals I've got to change/replace/extend.

Answer (score 0):

You must not place your view with your code files. In MVC you should have separate folders: `Models, Controllers, Views`. The MVC engine searches views in `Views` folder.

In your case in your `Views` folder you need to have subfolders `Authentication` and `Dashboard`. In each subfolder you place your `index` pages and other pages **related only to this part of application**. For example, if you have separate view `edit` for dashboard editing you place it in `Views - Dashboard`

The same is for controllers' classes. You have `Controllers` folder and subfolders `Dashboard, Authentication`. The same rule is for models' classes

For all `.js` files you should have `Scripts` folder, for all css rules - `Content` folder

And you do not need your custom `ViewEngine` for rendering pages. Its only needed if you have some non-generic templating or some business requirements

Comment: This is standard MVC architecture. My question is more about how to break it. My question is not about what the framework requires out of the box but about the framework internals.

Comment: Because it's not flexible enough.